# The Armature deforms my object unevenly, no matter what rotation I try. What am I missing?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints

I'm trying to animate a book opening, and have tried multiple different ways, but I can't get rid of this issue. The armature closes one side of the books crooked and the other straight. I have no idea where to go from here. Help[image: Closed book with arm below]

Comment: Hello, so how did you rigged your object? Maybe share your file so that we can take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here is the Blender FILE: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ArV5E0jR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ArV5E0jR/)

Comment: the rigging is not good, I don't know how you've parented but for this kind of object (non organic) you'd better parent With Empty Groups, it will create vertex groups that have the same name as the bones except that for the moment no vertices are assigned to these gorups, you are the one that is going to assign them with the Assign button under the Vertex Groups list, in properties > Object Data > Vertex Groups.